# Удаление файла с заданным расширением и размером через Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
if($file.Length -gt $size -and $file -eq "*.$widening")
{ 
    Remove-Item $file
}
```

В данном коде $file = сам файл, $size = его размер, $widening - расширение. Все этим параметры задает пользователь. Но код не работает, можете подсказать ,что не так? Код должен находить файл, размер которого больше $size и его расширение $widening

Comment: а как задается значение для $file? И что значит "не работает"? И почему -eq вместо -like? и почему $file вообще, если это string, то почему $file.length?

Comment: @MikhailSokolov, -eq - значит равно, то есть имя совпадает с маской. А $file.Length - размер файла

Comment: а где ответы на остальные вопросы? Если $file Это объект типа файл, то вы не можете сравнивать объект со строкой, вы должны брать свойство объекта в котором хранится имя. Или свойство объекта в котором хранится расширение. Если вы сравниваете с маской, то вы не должны использовать -eq, вы сами сказали что это "равно".

Comment: +1 за "widening" - "расширение".

Answer (score 0):

Если $file.GetType() это System.IO.FileInfo, то так:

```
if ($file.Length -gt 10 -and $file.Extension -eq '.txt' )
```

Или так:

```
if ($file.Length -gt 10 -and $file.Name -like "*.$widening" )
```